# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: When trying to move or copy file to another directory

Tags: python, excel, pandas, shutil

I am reading data from an excel spreadsheet(a list of textfiles) and using each row to retrieve the actual text file from a directory using Pycharm Community edition 2020 v1.3.  I've set up a small loop to test whether the algorithm is working.  When I try to print out the results it works perfectly, but when I attempt to move or copy the corresponding files to another directory I get the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:/Users/dalea/PycharmProjects/untitled/d1.py", line 46, in <module>
    shutil.copy(file, MDA_For_Parsing)  # Move it to MDA parsing directory
 File "C:\Users\dalea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 248, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
 File "C:\Users\dalea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '19940804_10-K_edgar_data_354952_0000891618-94-000152_1.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The search seems to be working as required, it's the copy or move statement which is the problem.  Can anyone explain why?  My code is as follows.

```
import re
import glob
import os,sys
import csv
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import fnmatch
import string
import xlrd
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile

MDA_Path = 'D:/1994_QTR3' # contains Loughram and MacDonald 10-K files

MDA_Target_List = r'D:/PhD_Data/Wenrui_Filing_list' # stores wenruis data

# MDA_For_Parsing = 'D:/Required_MDA_1994_QTR3' # will hold all 10-Ks from wenrui's spreadsheet once detected

MDA_For_Parsing = 'D:/Test'

# open the CSV file and extract the column containing the location of the text file(s)

datas = pd.read_excel(r'D:/PhD_Data/Wenrui_Filing_list/1994-2017filingslist_Wenrui_13Jul2020.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns = ['FILE_NAME'])  # extract the data contained in FILE_NAME column

df['FILE_NAME'] = df['FILE_NAME'].str[26:]  # remove the first 26 characters which contain the edgar drive info

df['FILE_NAME'] = df['FILE_NAME'].str.strip() # remove all leading and trailing


file_length = len(df) # count number of files in Wenrui's list (will need this later to loop through all occurrences)
dirs = os.listdir(MDA_Path)

for x in range(6): # if the L&M file exists in Wenrui's data set

 for file in dirs:
 # if file == df['FILE_NAME'][x]:
   if df['FILE_NAME'][x] in file:
      print(file)
      shutil.copy(file, MDA_For_Parsing)  # Move it to MDA parsing directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.listdir(MDA_Path) only returns the base file names. The names do not include the folder.

Ti fix you issue, include the path when you do the copy:

```
shutil.copy(MDA_Path + '/' + file, MDA_For_Parsing)
```